# Using flymake with meson build system

Tags: flymake

Good morning,

I have been using flymake for a long time with autoconf/automake adding this at the end of the Makefile.am:

```
check-syntax:
    $(CXXCOMPILE) -Wall -fsyntax-only $(CHK_SOURCES)

.PHONY: check-syntax
```

Now that I'm switching some projects to [meson](https://mesonbuild.com/), how do I configure flymake ?

Despite searching I couldn't find anything, thank you for your help.

Comment: https://mesonbuild.com/Custom-build-targets.html